# Reflecting inner struct in outer struct initialization

Tags: c, arrays, compound-literals

I have a code of structs stated as below:

```
typedef struct A {
  B numberOfB[3];
} A;

typedef struct B {
  int number1;
  int number2;
  boolean bool1;
  boolean bool2;
} B;
```

In the source code I have an initialization which looks like this:

```
A* pointerToA = (A[3]) {

  {5, 1, TRUE, TRUE,
   6, 1, TRUE, FALSE,
   7, 1, TRUE, FALSE},

  {5, 1, TRUE, TRUE,
   6, 1, TRUE, FALSE,
   7, 1, TRUE, FALSE},

  {5, 1, TRUE, TRUE,
   6, 1, TRUE, FALSE,
   7, 1, TRUE, FALSE},
}
```

Such construction in source code is updating fields in `struct B` but I do not understand how are fields in `B` are updated as the values are just listed as it was a array of 12 values. Could someone explain that in details?

Comment: The  C Standard does explain how it works, but it takes most of a page to do so and adds copious examples. It works, but it is better to use more braces.  GCC has options which warn about missing braces in initializers.

Comment: The rules are somewhat voluminous, but, basically, if your braces follow the structures, fine. If you omit braces, C descends into (and out of) arrays and structures for you.

Comment: So, if you want to create very unreadable code, you can remove those braces around each `A` in the array of 3 as well...

Comment: I might suggest changing the title. This question is not specific to compound literals. It applies to initialization generally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflecting the substructure in an initializer is optional. So here having 12 value is sufficient to initialize an `A`.

This is really bad style though, I think, since it makes the code quite difficult to read. Much better would even be to use designated initializers such that the initialization becomes robust versus changes of the structure. Something like

```
[0] = {.number1 = 5, .number2 = 1, .bool1 = true, .bool2 = true, },
```

Also observe that C has a proper Boolean type and constants that you best use through the header `<stdbool.h>` as `bool`, `false` and `true`.

Comment: Isn't that a C99 initialization?

Comment: The thing is what happens here is that there are 12 initializers for one B, I believe the behaviour to be undefined

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: There are 12 initializers for one A, and A contains 12 subobjects.

Comment: @Er"icPostpischil yea, it is the footnote "148) If the initializer list for a subaggregate or contained union does not begin with a left brace, its subobjects are initialized as usual, but the subaggregate or contained union does not become the current object: current objects are associated only with brace-enclosed initializer lists.

Comment: @RingØ, yes, I think designated initializers came with C99, 18 years ago, as came also compound literals that are used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Compound literal actually introduced from the C99:

A compound literal it looks like doing a  cast containing an initializer. Its value is an object of the type specified in the cast, containing the elements specified in the initializer; it is an lvalue.

In C, a compound literal designates an unnamed object with static or automatic storage duration.

Semantics for simple compound literal. Below is just the sample struct initialization using compound literal.

```
 struct sample {int a; int b;} struct_obj;
```

This is how you construct the compound literal for struct_obj.

```
 struct_obj = ((struct sample) {1, 2});
```

This is equivalent to

```
 {
   struct foo temp = {1, 2};
   structure = temp;
 }
```

In your case, struct A is initialized with array values.

```
A* pointerToA = (A[3]) {..... } // here A[3] is initialized with the values in your array.
```

Comment: Yes you're absolutely correct, but you're not beginning to answer the question.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I just checked this question got an answer already.